# Log all .htaccess/.htpasswd logins and password when accessing .mp4 file

Tags: php, .htaccess

Basically, I have this setting in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI} index1.php [L]
ErrorDocument 401 /video.mp4
AuthName "My Password Protected Site"
AuthUserFile /var/www/PATH/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
# Set REMOTE_USER env variable on 401 ErrorDocument
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^401$
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{ENV:REDIRECT_REMOTE_USER}]
```

and a PHP file that redirects login and password

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'])):
    $fp = fopen(MYLOGFILE, 'a+');
    $password = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'];
    $username = $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'];
    $time = date('y-m-d/H:i:s');
    $request = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
    fwrite($fp, $time . "\t" . $request . "\t" . $username . "/" . $password . "\r\n");
    fclose($fp);
endif;
ob_start();
header("HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required",1);
header("Status: 401 Authorization Required",1);
echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head><body>
<h1>Authorization Required</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you are authorized to
 access the document
 requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
 credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
 browser doesn\'t understand how to supply
 the credentials required . </p>';
exit();
?>
```

There is logging of username and password if I point to the PHP file in .htaccess and directly go to the file. But if I do a redirect from PHP to mp4, it doesn't work. We tried to solve this mystery but no luck. Everything works fine on here https://serverfault.com/questions/460765/log-invalid-login-attempts-htpasswd.

The goal is to get basic auth creds when filling them on the .mp4$ page. I've done it with .php$, but when a PHP code is on the .mp4 page, creds are not logged.

Comment: One should _never_ log authentication credentials. This sounds fishy...

Comment: @arkascha, I need it for test purposes; it's for my secret project.

Comment: Same problem, I'm trying to debug (failed) logins on a shared hosting, where I can't access apache logs. Doesn't seem to work without pointing to the specific file.